# Minimal Turing Machine implementation / Von Neumann UC

Tags: computability, automata-theory, turing-machines, machine-models, cellular-automata

I've written a small python program which implements a Turing Machine with a finite tape. It has a tape, a head, a state register and a set of transfer functions ("the program"). The difference to a TM is that when the head reaches the end of the tape, a separate state is triggered: 'end of tape left' and 'end of tape right'.

Now, my experimental idea is to have the transition table in memory so that I have a more "complete" virtual machine, along the lines of a Von Neumann Universal Constructor (not quite the same). What is the minimal program that can run other programs in memory? I'm interested in a different structure of a minimal computing machine, where the transition table is closer to a machine instruction set and can be hold in memory. This will certainly bloat the structure - I'm fine with that. This would be something like a minimal machine which implements an operating system.

Comment: downvotes without comments. annoying

Comment: cstheory is for research level questions (see [FAQ](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/faq) ), cs.stackexchange.com should be the correct site for questions like this. And answering to it, I exposed myself to (deserverd) downvotes, too :-) :-), but a few days ago I finally understood the details of Rogozinh's 2 states 18 symbols UTM ... so I zestful answered to your question.

Comment: Welcome to cstheory, a Q&A site for *research-level* questions in *theoretical computer science* (TCS). Your question does not appear to be a research-level question in TCS. Please see the [FAQ] for more information on what is meant by this. The questions seems more suitable for [cs.se] which has a broader scope.

Comment: PS: users are not required to explain their down-votes on cstheory. Often reading the [FAQ] can help you find out the reason for the down-vote.

Comment: downvotes without comments are just as annoying as out-of-scope questions without reading [FAQ].

Comment: Now I remember why I left academia. Who defines what research is? No thanks. Probably a good reason why research and the internet often don't connect. Goodbye.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the " $U$s " in the first table of the paper "[Small Turing Machines ...](http://www.dm.unito.it/~cerruti/ac/paperpm1.pdf)". For example, 2 states and 18 symbols are enough to build a Turing Machine that can execute an operating system (if you augment it with an adequate I/O mechanism :) ...

If you look for small models closer to the Von Neumann architecture then take a look at [Random-access stored-program machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_stored-program_machine)

From Wikipedia: *... The RASP is a [random-access machine (RAM) model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_machine) that, unlike the RAM, has its program in its "registers" together with its input....*

The instruction set has only 3 opcodes: INC, DEC and JZ

See also [S.A. Cook and R.A. Reckhow, "Time Bounded Random Access Machines"](http://www.cs.utoronto.ca/~sacook/homepage/rams.pdf) (they use a larger ALGOL-like set of instructions).